# I have an SVG map with markers displayed randomly. I can I place them accurately to tell the actual location on the SVG map?

Tags: javascript, svg

With the random markers I have on my SVG map, I want to place them accurately within the SVG map which is the actual location map.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
// the number of random points on the map
let circlesLength = 30;
// the bounding box of the path
let bb = thePath.getBBox();
//set the svg viewBox attribute
svg.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox",`${bb.x} ${bb.y} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}`)

// svg client rect
let cr = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

let n = 0;//a counter

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  // get a random point on the svg canvas
  let x = randomIntFromInterval(cr.x,(cr.x+cr.width));
  let y = randomIntFromInterval(cr.y,(cr.y+cr.height));

  //elementFromPoint returns the topmost Element at the specified coordinates (relative to the viewport).
  let elmt = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  // if the point is in path
  if(elmt.className.baseVal == "path"){
    //get the coordinates of the point on the svg 
    let svgPoint = getPoint(x,y); 
    //draw a circle with the center on the svg point
    drawCircle({cx:svgPoint.x,cy:svgPoint.y,r:.01}, svg)

    //incerase the counter
    n++

  };
  // if you have already 6 points break the loop
  if(n == circlesLength){break;}
}

// a function to get a random integer from an interval
function randomIntFromInterval(mn, mx) {
  return ~~(Math.random() * (mx - mn + 1) + mn);
}

// a function to get the svg coordinates of a point on the svg canvas
function getPoint(x,y){  
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = x;
      p.y = y;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}

// a function to draw a circle
function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible;}
path{stroke:black;vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;fill:gold;}
circle{fill:red;}
```

```html
<svg height=200 width=200 fill="none" viewBox='.6 1.1 1 1'>
<defs>
   <symbol id="marker" viewBox="1.4 1.7 16 16">
   <g transform="translate(0.0625 0.0475)">
     <circle r="2" cx="8" cy="8" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.001" fill="red"/>
     </g>
   </symbol>
  </defs>

  <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#marker" width=".15" height=".15" x="1.05" y="1.55" />

 <path d='M 1.08583,1.84181 l 0.02003,0.00322 0.003917,-0.008192 0.001098,-0.00409 0.001925,-0.003735 0.003098,-0.007964 0.001112,-0.002924 0.000531,-0.003501 0.001664,-0.004677 0.001465,-0.004257 0.004778,-0.001624 0.004599,0.000546 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.002289,-0.000602 0.005166,-4.2e-05 0.003443,-2.9e-05 0.001701,-0.001762 0.001105,-0.003507 -0.001184,-0.002905 -0.001198,-0.00407 -0.002346,-0.004061 -0.002339,-0.003479 -0.001633,-0.00216 -0.00245,-0.003053 -0.001757,-0.0029 -0.003488,-0.003469 -0.004053,-0.002881 -0.004047,-0.002299 -0.004628,-0.002877 -0.00231,-0.001147 -0.004054,-0.002881 -0.002891,-0.001726 -0.002885,-0.001142 -0.003465,-0.00172 -0.004039,-0.001716 -0.003466,-0.001721 -0.002318,-0.00173 -0.002331,-0.002895 -0.001766,-0.003483 0.000546,-0.002336 -0.000624,-0.004076 0.000538,-0.002918 -5.7e-05,-0.004663 0.001055,-0.007587 -0.000646,-0.005824 0.000516,-0.004667 0.000532,-0.003502 0.002216,-0.00643 0.006286,-0.002384 0.009184,-7.4e-05 0.00518,0.001123 0.005173,0.000541 0.004613,0.001711 0.004585,-0.00062 0.006881,-0.000639 0.005159,-0.000625 0.004003,-0.001199 0.003423,-0.001776 0.004011,-0.000616 0.00226,-0.002933 0.001105,-0.003507 0.001679,-0.003511 0.003968,-0.004113 0.002863,-0.000606 0.003487,0.003469 3.5e-05,0.002915 0.00061,0.002909 0.002892,0.001725 0.003465,0.001721 0.007512,0.004019 0.008079,0.003431 0.009844,0.006915 0.002339,0.003478 0.002346,0.004062 0.001929,0.004325 0.001601,0.002641 0.00635,0.002862 0.004613,0.001712 0.006903,0.001109 0.00805,0.0011 0.002877,0.00056 0.003451,0.000554 0.004606,0.001129 0.00404,0.001716 0.002325,0.002312 0.00175,0.002318 0.001184,0.002905 0.001765,0.003482 0.001758,0.002901 0.007505,0.003436 0.006888,-5.6e-05 0.004011,-0.000616 0.003429,-0.001194 0.059804,-0.085011 0.004557,-0.002951 0.005122,-0.003539 0.007391,-0.00589 0.002841,-0.002355 0.044101,0.019307 0.00433,-0.002215 0.001097,-0.004089
 0.004492,-0.008197 -0.00374,-0.003618 -0.005432,-0.002823 -0.001808,-0.001864 -0.003619,-0.002806 -0.004524,-0.002814 -0.007249,-0.001916 -0.003618,-0.002806 -0.003619,-0.002805 -0.004531,-0.000967 -0.002718,-0.00095 -0.003624,-0.000958 -0.003618,-0.002805 -0.002714,-0.001873 -0.00452,-0.004663 -0.000895,-0.003703 -0.003607,-0.006501 -0.003609,-0.005576 -0.004526,-0.002815 -0.00542,-0.006518 -0.006327,-0.006526 -0.001804,-0.002789 -0.001808,-0.001864 -0.003613,-0.004653 -0.004528,-0.001891 -0.003633,0.001814 -0.003636,0.002736 -0.005455,0.004568 -0.00454,0.001804 -0.002729,0.002746 -0.005459,0.005491 -0.004548,0.004576 -0.006363,0.004558 -0.009088,0.006381 -0.004531,-0.000967 -0.005441,-5.1e-05 -0.004537,0.000881 -0.00454,0.001804 -0.005437,-0.000975 -0.002712,-0.002797 -0.001793,-0.006484 2.1e-05,-0.006466 0.000927,-0.006458 0.002743,-0.007364 0.000949,-0.012924 -0.00175,-0.02034 -0.00086,-0.014789 -0.000862,-0.013865 -0.001767,-0.014797 -0.003539,-0.027747 -0.001779,-0.011103 -0.003601,-0.008348 -0.002702,-0.005568 -0.004523,-0.003738 -0.004513,-0.006509 -0.007219,-0.011154 -0.008105,-0.017629 -0.003604,-0.007424 -0.007223,-0.01023 -0.007218,-0.011154 -0.012646,-0.015824 -0.014491,-0.00568 -0.004171,-3.9e-05 -0.004022,0.010123 -0.001832,0.005526 -0.002746,0.008287 -0.002741,0.006441 -0.001828,0.004602 -0.000925,0.005534 -0.000918,0.003686 -0.000925,0.005534 -0.002741,0.006441 -0.005458,0.005491 -0.003645,0.005508 -0.003639,0.00366 -0.00545,0.00272 -0.005446,0.001796 -0.006353,0.001788 -0.007258,0.000855 -0.009989,0.004524 -0.009083,0.004533 -0.004543,0.002729 -0.003648,0.006431 -0.003644,0.005509 -0.004555,0.006423 -0.003644,0.005509 -0.002733,0.003668 -0.001825,0.003679 -0.005464,0.007338 -0.004543,0.002728 -0.004543,0.002729 -0.00272,-2.6e-05 -0.008155,-0.001925 -0.00906,-0.002857 -0.005431,-0.002823 -0.007261,0.001779 -0.009068,-8.6e-05 -0.002712,-0.002797
 -0.002702,-0.005568 -0.006336,-0.003755 -0.002729,0.002745 -0.004537,0.000881 -0.002712,-0.002797 -0.005431,-0.002823 -0.005438,-0.000975 -0.004537,0.000881 -0.007276,0.006397 -0.003644,0.005508 -0.004551,0.0055 -0.004547,0.003652 -0.00501,0.001292 -0.013143,0.004079 -0.00817,0.002694 -0.009083,0.004533 -0.006359,0.003635 -0.005455,0.004567 -0.005456,0.004568 -0.005261,0.004939 0.002906,0.002891 0.001772,0.004066 0.00292,0.004056 0.004642,0.004043 0.002328,0.003456 0.000621,0.002932 -0.000538,0.002919 -0.001119,0.00234 -0.001701,0.001763 -0.001679,0.003512 -0.001679,0.003511 -0.001119,0.002341 -0.000538,0.002919 0.001176,0.002321 0.001184,0.002905 -0.000545,0.002337 -0.000481,0.007582 0.001765,0.003483 0.004032,0.001132 0.004032,0.001133 0.005748,0.000536 0.004032,0.001133 0.003458,0.001138 0.0046,0.000545 0.005238,0.001713 0.004548,0.000539 0.002699,-0.000692 0.007066,0.001196 0.004025,0.000549 0.002877,0.00056 0.003451,0.000555 0.003452,0.000554 0.00231,0.001148 0.005819,0.006364 3.6e-05,0.002914 0.000609,0.00291 -0.000545,0.002336 -0.005704,0.002961 -0.002849,0.001772 -0.002246,0.004099 -0.001111,0.002924 3.5e-05,0.002914 5.1e-05,0.00408 0.002346,0.004061 0.001183,0.002905 0.001177,0.002322 -0.001119,0.002341 -0.002849,0.001772 -0.001657,0.00526 0.00061,0.002909 -0.004535,0.004701 -0.001119,0.00234 -0.000524,0.004085 0.002927,0.00464 0.001191,0.003487 0.001192,0.003488 0.000609,0.00291 0.001184,0.002905 0.00175,0.002317 0.002325,0.002313 0.001744,0.001734 0.003465,0.001721 0.002311,0.001147 3.5e-05,0.002914 4.3e-05,0.003497 -0.000545,0.002337 -0.002224,0.005846 -0.005719,0.001796 -0.003429,0.001194 -0.004004,0.001199 -0.005166,4.1e-05 -0.00287,2.4e-05 -0.005589,0.012287 -0.001105,0.003506 -0.001679,0.003512 -0.001672,0.004094 -0.005123,0.003539 0.000681,0.008738 0.002356,0.005182 0.001799,0.00586 5.7e-05,0.004662 0.001191,0.003489 0.005726,-0.001213 0.002855,-0.001189 0.00231,0.001147 0.002318,0.001729 0.001758,0.002901 0.001779,0.004648 0.002332,0.002896 0.002346,0.004061 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.004585,-0.00062 0.002289,-0.000602 0.005144,-0.001791 0.007477,0.001105 0.0021,0.000987 0.00887,0.00417 0.004082,0.005213 0.00409,0.005796 0.002331,0.002895 -0.000545,0.002336 0.00178,0.00465 0.000631,0.004657 0.001184,0.002906 0.002339,0.003478 0.004068,0.004047 0.002906,0.002891 0.004621,0.002294 0.002905,0.002891 0.005116,0.002664 0.050227,0.008073 z'></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your code does not run. `thePath` is not defined anywhere.  Secondly your question is unclear.  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need points placed accurately, this means you know where your points are on the map and you will need to save those points in an array of points, for example this:

```
let circlesArray = [
      {cx:1.11,cy:1.64,r:.01},
      {cx:1.23,cy:1.53,r:.01},
      {cx:1.03,cy:1.77,r:.01},
      {cx:1.18,cy:1.57,r:.01},
      {cx:0.99,cy:1.77,r:.01},
      {cx:1.25,cy:1.67,r:.01},
    ]
```

Once you have the array of points, for each one you draw the point on the map.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
// the number of random points on the map
let circlesArray = [
  {cx:1.11,cy:1.64,r:.01},
  {cx:1.23,cy:1.53,r:.01},
  {cx:1.03,cy:1.77,r:.01},
  {cx:1.18,cy:1.57,r:.01},
  {cx:0.99,cy:1.77,r:.01},
  {cx:1.25,cy:1.67,r:.01},
]


circlesArray.forEach(c=>{
  drawCircle(c, svg)
})




// a function to draw a circle
function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible;}
path{stroke:black;vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;fill:gold;}
circle{fill:red;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" height=200 width=200 fill="none" viewBox='.6 1.1 1 1'>
 <path class="path" id="thePath" d='M 1.08583,1.84181 l 0.02003,0.00322 0.003917,-0.008192 0.001098,-0.00409 0.001925,-0.003735 0.003098,-0.007964 0.001112,-0.002924 0.000531,-0.003501 0.001664,-0.004677 0.001465,-0.004257 0.004778,-0.001624 0.004599,0.000546 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.002289,-0.000602 0.005166,-4.2e-05 0.003443,-2.9e-05 0.001701,-0.001762 0.001105,-0.003507 -0.001184,-0.002905 -0.001198,-0.00407 -0.002346,-0.004061 -0.002339,-0.003479 -0.001633,-0.00216 -0.00245,-0.003053 -0.001757,-0.0029 -0.003488,-0.003469 -0.004053,-0.002881 -0.004047,-0.002299 -0.004628,-0.002877 -0.00231,-0.001147 -0.004054,-0.002881 -0.002891,-0.001726 -0.002885,-0.001142 -0.003465,-0.00172 -0.004039,-0.001716 -0.003466,-0.001721 -0.002318,-0.00173 -0.002331,-0.002895 -0.001766,-0.003483 0.000546,-0.002336 -0.000624,-0.004076 0.000538,-0.002918 -5.7e-05,-0.004663 0.001055,-0.007587 -0.000646,-0.005824 0.000516,-0.004667 0.000532,-0.003502 0.002216,-0.00643 0.006286,-0.002384 0.009184,-7.4e-05 0.00518,0.001123 0.005173,0.000541 0.004613,0.001711 0.004585,-0.00062 0.006881,-0.000639 0.005159,-0.000625 0.004003,-0.001199 0.003423,-0.001776 0.004011,-0.000616 0.00226,-0.002933 0.001105,-0.003507 0.001679,-0.003511 0.003968,-0.004113 0.002863,-0.000606 0.003487,0.003469 3.5e-05,0.002915 0.00061,0.002909 0.002892,0.001725 0.003465,0.001721 0.007512,0.004019 0.008079,0.003431 0.009844,0.006915 0.002339,0.003478 0.002346,0.004062 0.001929,0.004325 0.001601,0.002641 0.00635,0.002862 0.004613,0.001712 0.006903,0.001109 0.00805,0.0011 0.002877,0.00056 0.003451,0.000554 0.004606,0.001129 0.00404,0.001716 0.002325,0.002312 0.00175,0.002318 0.001184,0.002905 0.001765,0.003482 0.001758,0.002901 0.007505,0.003436 0.006888,-5.6e-05 0.004011,-0.000616 0.003429,-0.001194 0.059804,-0.085011 0.004557,-0.002951 0.005122,-0.003539 0.007391,-0.00589 0.002841,-0.002355 0.044101,0.019307 0.00433,-0.002215 0.001097,-0.004089 0.004492,-0.008197 -0.00374,-0.003618 -0.005432,-0.002823 -0.001808,-0.001864 -0.003619,-0.002806 -0.004524,-0.002814 -0.007249,-0.001916 -0.003618,-0.002806 -0.003619,-0.002805 -0.004531,-0.000967 -0.002718,-0.00095 -0.003624,-0.000958 -0.003618,-0.002805 -0.002714,-0.001873 -0.00452,-0.004663 -0.000895,-0.003703 -0.003607,-0.006501 -0.003609,-0.005576 -0.004526,-0.002815 -0.00542,-0.006518 -0.006327,-0.006526 -0.001804,-0.002789 -0.001808,-0.001864 -0.003613,-0.004653 -0.004528,-0.001891 -0.003633,0.001814 -0.003636,0.002736 -0.005455,0.004568 -0.00454,0.001804 -0.002729,0.002746 -0.005459,0.005491 -0.004548,0.004576 -0.006363,0.004558 -0.009088,0.006381 -0.004531,-0.000967 -0.005441,-5.1e-05 -0.004537,0.000881 -0.00454,0.001804 -0.005437,-0.000975 -0.002712,-0.002797 -0.001793,-0.006484 2.1e-05,-0.006466 0.000927,-0.006458 0.002743,-0.007364 0.000949,-0.012924 -0.00175,-0.02034 -0.00086,-0.014789 -0.000862,-0.013865 -0.001767,-0.014797 -0.003539,-0.027747 -0.001779,-0.011103 -0.003601,-0.008348 -0.002702,-0.005568 -0.004523,-0.003738 -0.004513,-0.006509 -0.007219,-0.011154 -0.008105,-0.017629 -0.003604,-0.007424 -0.007223,-0.01023 -0.007218,-0.011154 -0.012646,-0.015824 -0.014491,-0.00568 -0.004171,-3.9e-05 -0.004022,0.010123 -0.001832,0.005526 -0.002746,0.008287 -0.002741,0.006441 -0.001828,0.004602 -0.000925,0.005534 -0.000918,0.003686 -0.000925,0.005534 -0.002741,0.006441 -0.005458,0.005491 -0.003645,0.005508 -0.003639,0.00366 -0.00545,0.00272 -0.005446,0.001796 -0.006353,0.001788 -0.007258,0.000855 -0.009989,0.004524 -0.009083,0.004533 -0.004543,0.002729 -0.003648,0.006431 -0.003644,0.005509 -0.004555,0.006423 -0.003644,0.005509 -0.002733,0.003668 -0.001825,0.003679 -0.005464,0.007338 -0.004543,0.002728 -0.004543,0.002729 -0.00272,-2.6e-05 -0.008155,-0.001925 -0.00906,-0.002857 -0.005431,-0.002823 -0.007261,0.001779 -0.009068,-8.6e-05 -0.002712,-0.002797 -0.002702,-0.005568 -0.006336,-0.003755 -0.002729,0.002745 -0.004537,0.000881 -0.002712,-0.002797 -0.005431,-0.002823 -0.005438,-0.000975 -0.004537,0.000881 -0.007276,0.006397 -0.003644,0.005508 -0.004551,0.0055 -0.004547,0.003652 -0.00501,0.001292 -0.013143,0.004079 -0.00817,0.002694 -0.009083,0.004533 -0.006359,0.003635 -0.005455,0.004567 -0.005456,0.004568 -0.005261,0.004939 0.002906,0.002891 0.001772,0.004066 0.00292,0.004056 0.004642,0.004043 0.002328,0.003456 0.000621,0.002932 -0.000538,0.002919 -0.001119,0.00234 -0.001701,0.001763 -0.001679,0.003512 -0.001679,0.003511 -0.001119,0.002341 -0.000538,0.002919 0.001176,0.002321 0.001184,0.002905 -0.000545,0.002337 -0.000481,0.007582 0.001765,0.003483 0.004032,0.001132 0.004032,0.001133 0.005748,0.000536 0.004032,0.001133 0.003458,0.001138 0.0046,0.000545 0.005238,0.001713 0.004548,0.000539 0.002699,-0.000692 0.007066,0.001196 0.004025,0.000549 0.002877,0.00056 0.003451,0.000555 0.003452,0.000554 0.00231,0.001148 0.005819,0.006364 3.6e-05,0.002914 0.000609,0.00291 -0.000545,0.002336 -0.005704,0.002961 -0.002849,0.001772 -0.002246,0.004099 -0.001111,0.002924 3.5e-05,0.002914 5.1e-05,0.00408 0.002346,0.004061 0.001183,0.002905 0.001177,0.002322 -0.001119,0.002341 -0.002849,0.001772 -0.001657,0.00526 0.00061,0.002909 -0.004535,0.004701 -0.001119,0.00234 -0.000524,0.004085 0.002927,0.00464 0.001191,0.003487 0.001192,0.003488 0.000609,0.00291 0.001184,0.002905 0.00175,0.002317 0.002325,0.002313 0.001744,0.001734 0.003465,0.001721 0.002311,0.001147 3.5e-05,0.002914 4.3e-05,0.003497 -0.000545,0.002337 -0.002224,0.005846 -0.005719,0.001796 -0.003429,0.001194 -0.004004,0.001199 -0.005166,4.1e-05 -0.00287,2.4e-05 -0.005589,0.012287 -0.001105,0.003506 -0.001679,0.003512 -0.001672,0.004094 -0.005123,0.003539 0.000681,0.008738 0.002356,0.005182 0.001799,0.00586 5.7e-05,0.004662 0.001191,0.003489 0.005726,-0.001213 0.002855,-0.001189 0.00231,0.001147 0.002318,0.001729 0.001758,0.002901 0.001779,0.004648 0.002332,0.002896 0.002346,0.004061 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.003444,-2.8e-05 0.004585,-0.00062 0.002289,-0.000602 0.005144,-0.001791 0.007477,0.001105 0.0021,0.000987 0.00887,0.00417 0.004082,0.005213 0.00409,0.005796 0.002331,0.002895 -0.000545,0.002336 0.00178,0.00465 0.000631,0.004657 0.001184,0.002906 0.002339,0.003478 0.004068,0.004047 0.002906,0.002891 0.004621,0.002294 0.002905,0.002891 0.005116,0.002664 0.050227,0.008073 z'></path>
  
  
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help accorded all along working with SVGs. I can confidently say have learnt loads from you. Works as expected